# Dynamic route for sitemap in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I need to create a dynamic router for the sitemaps.
They are located on the urls

```
example.com/sitemap-0.xml

example.com/sitemap-1.xml
```

I tried to create a page

```
[sitemap].xml.js
```

But it didn't work.

How to create a dynamic router for multiple sitemaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer. You can't.

You have to put your sitemaps into the public folder in order to be accessible. You can write a bash script that auto-generates the sitemaps in the build step. Find more information [here](https://codebycorey.com/blog/nextjs-sitemap).